# Disable cross-slide selection for a listview

Tags: listview, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, gesture

I'm designing an app that has a vertically panning one-dimensional list in the centre and the user is able to flip between lists horizontally due to a flipview.

[image: A vertically panning one-dimensional list]

When a user drags horizontally within the listview, it selects that row because of [cross-slide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465299.aspx). This isn't the behaviour I want. Preferably I would want the flipview to start panning left and right.  I think it's something to do with [rails](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465310.aspx#Rails) because when the user pans diagonally, they can pan the flipview.

Cross-slide even happens when selectionmode is set to `None`

How do I disable cross-slide, or how do I ensure that when a user pans left and right that the flipview pans and not the listview items?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

IsSwipeEnabled="False" on the ListView might do the trick. You might also edit the ListView.ItemContainerStyle/ListViewItem template to disable some visual state feedback transitions.

Comment: A simple boolean property!? Hours of googling and this was the answer? I'm a mix of emotions! Thank you very much

Comment: I was confused too the first time I saw that. They call it cross-slide in the docs everywhere, but call the property "swipe"?