# WinRT : Just display list of items

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I want to display list of items in my Metro applications. And I want to **just display** them. I don't want any kind selection, mouse-over, keyboard control, or animation effects.

The items will be displayed with ItemTemplate, the list will be data-bound and I want scrolling (both vertical and horizontal).

What would be the simplest way to do this? The ListView has lots of defaults, that make "simply displaying" items a heroic task.

Answer (score 2):

The ListView can get rid of almost everything you want by setting SelectionMode="None" and IsHitTestVisible="False".  This will give you no selection or highlight of any elements with mouse or keyboard.  You will still get scrolling and supporting interactions for scrolling.  You will still get animations, however.

Otherwise, you will probably have to look at using an ItemsControl and ScrollViewer to get the effect you want.

Comment: Also note you can change the control templates to remove any visual feedback from VisualStateManager as [mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790894/how-to-disable-listviews-hover-and-tile-effects) in some previous [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774209/disable-cross-slide-selection-for-a-listview) about the same thing

Comment: I think there's a typo. Doing this, I do NOT get scrolling or supporting interactions for scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ItemsControl in the first instance.  You add your data template as you desire and use the ItemsPanel control to apply your layout.  For example, the StackPanel below allows the orientation to switch to horizontal.

```
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Source="{Binding ImageUri}" Width="40" Height="40" Margin="5" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
```